# what are sane open file descriptor limits on linux?

Tags: linux, ulimit, file-descriptors

Where can I get good guidance on sane values for open file descriptor limits on linux.

We have users asking for massive numbers as their limits and I am unsure of the impact of this and what should be considered before raising this kind of limit extremely high. 200 000 +

Comment: 200,000+ is not sane.

Comment: Depends on the program. For example, 200k sounds about right if the program expects to handle 200k simultaneous TCP connections in a single process, but it's a bit too high for other software.

Comment: So what are the considerations from a resources perspective. I understand that the kernel uses and into to address these descriptors and a very small struct to represent them in memory. The program in question is a Java application server which is a tier behind a web application. Typical limits I have seen in the same space are around 32000 the request seems excessive. the boxes are typically in a load balance cluster of vm's.